# How to creating something like facebook connect?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, saml

I need to create a centralized authentication website. Something like how facebook does with "Login with facebook", but instead of using facebook I would be using my own website. I've been search for 3 days and found a couple of terms but don't know exactly if that's what I should use.

I found these:

- OAUTH 2
- SAML
- Identity provider(All php projects were deprecated)

But still I don't if this is what I should be looking for.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you even try something yet?

Comment: Please atleast type writing something in google before asking question

Comment: Yes, but I just don't know if that's what i'm looking for.
Here's an example: http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/

Comment: Stackoverflow already uses that. [This might](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work) clear your thoughts.

Comment: Do you want to create your own authentication web service ? Have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) as your IDP.

If you then want to extend to Facebook, federate this with [Azure ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185967.aspx).

ACS provides authentication with:

- Facebook
- Google
- Yahoo
- Windows Live